# Contempt on the part of students

Tags: graduate-school, emotional-responses

At my university there is a program called "voluntary monitoring", where a student who has passed a certain subject can become the "monitor/tutor" of that discipline.

Among the functions of the monitor are:

1. Offer pedagogical support to the students assisted in the curricular components;
2. Provide regularly enrolled Undergraduate students with the opportunity to engage in a work plan of teaching activities that enable the improvement of knowledge and the development of attitudes, skills and competencies favorable to their academic training and professional;
3. Create conditions for theoretical-practical deepening and development of skills and competences related to the teaching activity;
4. Establish pedagogical practices and experiences that allow the interaction of the monitors with the faculty, students and technical-administrative staff.

I ended up willingly becoming a tutor in a discipline called real analysis. It turns out that because I advanced some disciplines, I became a monitor for my own classmates. From there my problems started.

A good part of my colleagues showed disinterest in participating in the monitoring and that affected me, I don't know if it's because I'm not considered the best student in the class and in addition to not attending, they didn't answer questions with me, but with the "best student in the class" and demanded that I provide templates for the exercise lists that the teacher passes, since according to them, THIS IS MY FUNCTION. Apart from a few things I noticed, like some of my colleagues going to monitor just to talk to those who were also there.

The semester ended and only the "best student" in the class and two other colleagues passed. I'm again as real analysis monitor and the same problem is happening. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

I feel that my teaching was horrible, and I'm doing this because being a monitor counts as a point in the master's admission test.

Comment: "Monitor" seems to me a strange word here, though maybe it's what your institution uses or a translation. Should it be "mentor" instead?

Comment: You can't force others to show interest in being tutored. if your teaching was in fact horrible, well, that makes it impossible, and if you are only doing this to get 'a point' for master's admission, well they probably have figured that out. Provide real value to them by helping them.

Comment: Is this essentially a teaching assistant role? Are you saying that students didn’t ask you questions but instead asked the best student among those currently enrolled?

Comment: @Dawn yes, sir...

Comment: A lot of what you wrote is unclear: a) I think by "colleagues" you mean "fellow monitors"? (not "fellow students"). But they're not colleagues in the sense of paid employees. b) *"A good part of my colleagues showed disinterest in participating in the monitoring..."* Do you mean the other students didn't want to be mentored by you in particular? or by any mentor? c) "only three students passed". Was that 3 out of 5? out of 10? need that missing context. What was the pass rate for other monitors? for previous semesters? d) "students [attending] just to talk..." So they just want exercise lists.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you do not give us enough back-ground, especially not the country where you are studying and teaching as the reaction of your classmates to you is probably culturally embedded.

Skepticism of a peer being put in front of them as a mentor / monitor is a common reaction and the reaction of your classmates has a flavor of mobbing to it, where a negative reaction of one group member is reinforced and radicalized by that of another group member. In such an atmosphere, evidence of your being competent is disregarded and contrary evidence blown up. This means that you did not have much of a chance in your first experience and your second one is not going to go any better. Assigning you as monitor to your peers was just a bad idea for which you are not responsible. It is also a recipe to have you become and remain an ineffective teacher, because the environment is just not conducive to learning how to teach.

At this point, it seems to be unlikely that your fellow students are interested in being tutored by you at all. I do not see any way for you to change this.

I hope that you have a supervisor that you can talk to and who has influence about assignments. Since you would have to be truly exceptional to be successful with monitoring, I hope that your supervisor agrees that this was just a bad assignment and allows you to pull out of it.

If this is impossible, try to do something simple and useful as going over past (as in previous years') examination questions or homework problems.